# subtracting a nth element on a combination of vectors

Tags: r, vector

I have 2 given vectors `x, y` each with length of 10 and I want to create a 3rd vector `z` which combines them like so:

```
z<-(sin(y1)/cos(x2),...,sin(y(n-1)/cos(x(n)) ) # with a length of 9.
```

I've tried to do it simply:

```
z<-(sin(y)/cos(x))
```

but i just cant get rid of the 10th element in vector `z`
im using `r`, any suggestions?

**follow up**

The next assingment is to find which elements of `z` have elements from `x` which are `x < 0.1`. The given vectors are

```
x <- seq(from=0.2, to=0.02 , by= -0.02)
y <- c(seq(from=0.02, to=0.1 , by=0.02), seq(from=0.08, to=0.00 , by= -0.02))
```

Comment: Maybe it's not important for you but you may want to consider that people are put off by unstructured writing with obvious disregard for orthography

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First question. Simple for loop:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y <- c(3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 11, 12)
z <- c()
for(i in 1:(length(x)-1)){
  z <- c(z, sin(x[i])/cos(y[i+1]))
}
```

The second one, as far as i understand the question:

```
x <- seq(from=0.2, to=0.02 , by= -0.02) 
y <- c(seq(from=0.02, to=0.1 , by=0.02), seq(from=0.08, to=0.00 , by= -0.02))

z <- c()
for(i in 1:(length(x)-1)){
  z <- c(z, sin(x[i])/cos(y[i+1]))
}
which(z<0.1) # gets their position
z[which(z<0.1)] # gets their value
```